# Why is a question about creating a file in PHP not about programming?

Tags: support, specific-question, closed-questions, reopen-closed

The question [File-writing script just creates empty file named "0"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67239036/file-writing-script-just-creates-empty-file-named-0) got closed as it

> does not appear to be about programming within the scope defined in the help center.

This is the close banner

[image: probably not about programming]

But it is about file writing in PHP! Why was it closed?

Comment: This looks like a typical typo to me and I assume it got closed as such.

Comment: It is a very common beginner mistake in languages with separate operators for numerical types and strings ([Bash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_%28Unix_shell%29), [Perl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl), [PHP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP), [Visual Basic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic), etc.). Thus, a duplicate exists somewhere among [the 21,221,076 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions) on Stack Overflow (though it may not be easy to find - partly due to literal operators being search engine unfriendly).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The post notice says "This question is not about programming within the scope defined in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)", which is a bit different than what you've read it as. It doesn't, necessarily, mean that the question is completely not about programming (although it's also applicable to such non-programming questions). It means that it's not within the scope that's defined in the [on-topic page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). That scope defines a *subset* of programming questions which are on-topic.

The closed notice displayed in the post notice is using a generic "does not meet guidelines" reason, because there wasn't agreement between the reasons specified when the three people voted to close. In fact, each close voter used a different close reason. All of the reasons which were used are applicable. In random order, the reasons which were used were:

- Needs details or clarity
  This reason is really a superset of "Needs debugging details" / "no MCVE/MRE", so if that reason applies, then this one could reasonably be said to apply.
- Not suitable for this site → Needs debugging details
  Debugging questions *require*:

  1. the desired behavior [You don't have this. You give no description of what the program is *intended/expected/desired* to do.]
  2. a specific problem or error, and
  3. the shortest code necessary to reproduce it (or if it's a tool question, then enough information about your setup such that we can duplicate the problem) *in the question itself*
- Not suitable for this site → Not reproducible or was caused by a typo
  The answer, which you've accepted indicates that the problem is you used `+` instead of `.`. While this may have been a conceptual error, it's also possible that it was just a typo.

Comment: I've always wondered if moderators can see individual close reasons and now I know the answer. I'm still curious though... Can you also see who chose which reason? And is that information available to you even before the question is closed (i.e., <=2 votes)?

Comment: @41686d6564 Yes and yes.

Comment: @41686d6564 - Actually, users with the "View Close Votes" privilege can view close votes before the question is closed (https://i.stack.imgur.com/UiZMI.png). this is actually from Retrocomputing but it should be the same situation here with the close votes

Comment: @Someone_who_likes_SE I'm aware of that. You can't, however, see the individual votes _after_ the question is closed or after _you_ have voted to close and the selected reasons are in a sub-menu.